# Combing two items related to diet from a Likert scale into a new variable

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data, likert, scales

Hi everybody,

I have a question related to some analysis I need to do for a paper. For my dependent variable, I want to measure fruit and vegetable consumption. In the questionnaire that I use fruit and vegetable consumption is asked separately, respondent's have indicated on two questions how often they consume fruit and vegetables (the answer categories range from never to multiple times a day). My promotor has advised me to combine the fruit and vegetable variables into a new continuous one but I'm not sure how to do this best. Would you have any tips?

Thank you a lot in advance!!

Comment: Hi Yasemin. Welcome to Cross Validated. At this current form, it's bit of vague what the question is. A touch of clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the vagueness! I have a survey in which I ask respondents the following statements: How often do you eat fruit? How often do you eat vegetables? The answer options range from never to multiple times a day. I want to create a new variable called fruit and vegetable consumption based on these questions but I don't know how I can do this best.